# How to serve static directory from "ng serve"

Tags: angular

Can I ask if there are any similar config for webpack dev server config like this:

```
devServer : {
    historyApiFallback : true,
    stats : 'minimal',
    contentBase: helpers.root('../src/static'),
  }
```

I want to serve static files from static directory like how the webpack dev server is serving files.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I got your quastion right, but if you're using Angular CLI, the `assets` under `src` folder can serve static files.

Comment: None of the provided answers here actually answer this question in a useful way. Files in assets require a re-launch of the application.

Answer (score 50):

Yes there sure is.

Look in the root of your Angular app for a file called `angular.json`. There's an entry called "assets". Add your static directories here. Anything under them will be served directly via `ng serve`. And when you go live, all of these files will be copied to the /dist directory so they'll be served in a production environment also.

```json
"projects": {
  "YourCoolProject": {
      "root": "",
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/assets", 
              "myOtherStaticFiles"   /* <-- Add *your* directory(s) here */
            ],
            "styles": [
            ...
```

p.s. Yes, I know you can't really comment JSON. Give me a break.

Comment: and don't forget a comma before you add another entry :)

Comment: How can I adjust this so that the assets are served in development, but NOT copied for production (in my case they are copied by a different dev process)?

Comment: I have a similar question to @SimonH.  In my case, I want to static files from an external directory, as in outside the UI source tree, that are added at runtime and linked to from within the UI via database rows.   In real environments, an Nginx proxy server will be configured to serve both the UI, environment static files (vs. application static) and as a proxy to REST services.    I want to test the "environment static" files on my desktop to make sure my app logic is correct before pushing it out.   Won't including another directory in angular.json bring those files into my distribution?

Comment: @SimonH There is an answer to that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297722/exclude-assets-in-production-build

Comment: If you're running locally via ng serve then you'll need to Ctrl-C and get it to restart before it'll pick up the change to angular.json.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is verified against Angular 8+. In cases where your static files are outside sourceDir (find in your angular.json file), for example somewhere in your node_modules then you need to add something like this your angular.json file:

```
    root: "",
    architect: {
      build: {
        options:{
          outputPath: "dist/smartui",
          assets: {
            {
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "node_modules/@cruxcode/smartpdf",
              "output": "smartpdf/"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Once you do this, whenever you will build your project or use ng serve, the assets from the `input` will be copied to the `output` you mentioned in the angular.json file as shown above. The `output` directory will appear in the `outputPath` directory once you build or serve it.

`glob` is matched inside the `input` directory.

Your assets will be available at `output/`. In the above example, I can access the assets in my code as follows
`<img src="smartpdf/web/index.html">`

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. In `angular.json`, you can use entries named `assets`. Whatever file or directory you include in `assets` value array, will be served via `ng serve`. Whatever you add in `projects/<your-project>/architect/build/options/assets`, will be served in *all* build configurations and included in `dist` directory of production build.

If you want something to be available only during development or testing, you can use [Build Configurations](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-configs). By default, you have a section `projects/`*<your-project>*`/architect/build/configurations/production`. So, you could add your own section, such as `../build/configurations/dev` (perhaps initially copying whatever is in `production` section). Then, you can add `assets` entry there. These assets won't be available in production configuration.

To launch `ng serve` to specific configuration, you use `--configuration` argument. For example, to match `dev` configuration:

```
ng serve --configuration=dev
```

---

Disclaimer: Didn't test above - just reading the manual :-)