# Exclude assets in production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have some assets (images, styles) which I only need during development (ng serve). These assets must not be included in the production build. In production these assets are provided by a CDN.

I need:

- ng serve should serve files contained in the folder
  ./assets-non-build

but:

- ng build should not inculde the folder ./assets-non-build in the
  final build

I have worked through 10 similar questions here on SO and 5 issues on github, they all deal with excluding files, but none solved my situation.

Comment: Probably you need to exclude your `assets` folder from angular.json configuration, Have you removed that?

Comment: If I remove it from the angular.json, the files within that asset-folder wont be served by ng serve anymore ( I load them via an ajax-request)

Comment: Not tried yet, but there are two options one is for build and another one is for serve, so probably you need to set those as per requirements

Comment: that sounds interesting! How do I set options for build and serve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside your `angular.json` there is a configurations object `projects.{project-name}.architect.build.configurations`.

Set the `assets` inside the prod entry to `[]`

```
"production": {
  //...
  "assets": []
}
```

This is untested though, but by judging from what I know from the configuration file, this should be possible.

This will make any build and serve with the production flag to exclude the assets. If you really want all the builds, no matter the environment, to build without assets, you move the `assets` array from `projects.{project-name}.architect.build.options` to the `projects.{project-name}.architect.serve.options` and set the one in `build` to an empty array.

Comment: But assets will be available for `serve` only?

Comment: when using prod it says: "Configuration 'production' could not be found in project", I could solve this by  renaming "prod" to "production"

Comment: it depends on how you named the configuration, but the default is prod :) that's why I reverted it

Comment: architect->build->options->assets: ["my-dev-only-asset.css"] will be available for serve

Comment: Setting property `projects.{project-name}.architect.serve.options.assets` does not work anymore on angular 9 or perhaps even earlier (CLI 9.1.1 here): `ng serve` outputs `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets)`

Answer (score 3):

This answer describes how to handle large assets in dev + production (using angular 12+) using GCP, but you can easily adapt this answer for other clouds or environments.

The main idea

- Localhost: use assets stored src/local-assets/ locally. *Gitignore files in this folder (except maybe a .keep file) or use git-lfs to avoid polluting your repository with binary files*
- Production: upload the assets to your CDN, and replace the links by the CDN hostname

### 1 - Setup Angular to serve local assets

[Angular Documentation reference](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration)

This assumes you have some large or localhost only assets under src/large-assets. We're using angular object syntax to make them available under `assets/`
(Also make sure `src/large-assets` is gitignored, or under git-lfs)

```
# angular.json
"projects": {
    "[your-project-name]": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
            "development": {
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets",
                {
                  "glob": "**/*",
                  "input": "src/large-assets/",
                  "output": "/assets/"
                }
```

### 2 - Make assets URL environment specific

```
# src/environments/environment.ts
export const environment = {
  ...
  assetsUrl: 'https://localhost:4200/assets/',
  ...
};
# src/environments/environment.prod.ts
const GCP_PROJECT_NAME = 'gcp-project-name';
export const environment = {
  ...
  assetsUrl: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${GCP_PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com/assets/`,
  ...
};
```

### 3 - Setup Angular to replace environment in prod

```
# angular.json
"projects": {
    "[your-project-name]": {
     "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
             "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

### 4 - Use in components

```
# src/components/mycomponent.ts
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

```
# src/components/mycomponent.html
<img [src]="environment.assetsUrl + 'images/myimage.jpeg'" alt="alt">
```

### 5 - Upload your local large assets to CDN for production use

This is an example using GCP

```bash
gsutil cp -r src/large-assets gs://${GCP_PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com/
gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://${GCP_PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com/
```

In case you need to retrieve the assets previously uploaded in your bucket (new developer, switching computer)

```bash
gsutil -m cp -r gs://${GCP_PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com/assets/\* frontend/src/local-assets/
```

Answer (score 0):

PS: Code not tried yet but for comment its getting too long so posting as answer here.

```
"architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        ....
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                             ...
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                }
```

Comment: I tried this approach also, as it seems "assets" is not allowed under "serve". But thank you for you help! :-)

Comment: @TobiasGassmann your welcome, but accepted answer is not similer to mine somewhere?

Comment: Haha, my bad luck :P Anyways thanks for your comment on accepted answer, now got something new :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer from Poul Kruijt is correct for older versions of angular.
On Angular 9 `prod` entry do not work for me. You have to use `production` instead.
So that is what works for me in angular 9.