# Serving a static page as index.html (so as root page) in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, static, routes, assets

I'm facing the following issue:
I have a bought HTML template with some Jquery JS CSS... Which is ok for me as a static page but at the blog section, I'm using angular.
So somehow **I want to use that template as the index.html** and just run my angular app when the user navigates to that section.
I'm pretty sure that the problem is coming from the routing, but I don't know how to solve it without routing.

I copied my full template to my assets folder, and from the browser, I can run it if I navigate to http://localhost:4200/assets/index.html it loads js Jquery CSS perfectly.

So now:

**How can I set to reach this template at just http://localhost:4200/ ?**

**And then how can I navigate from it to my angular app ?**

this is how my routes looks like now:

```
const routes: Routes = [  { path: "", redirectTo: "/blog", pathMatch: "full"},  { path: "", loadChildren: "./posts/posts.module#PostsModule" }
```

];

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646504/how-to-serve-static-directory-from-ng-serve
did you try this?
Or this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5029#issuecomment-403045138

Comment: Hey, yes both of them. The problem is not to serve static files, but to serve it as root, so as index.html and then from it navigate to my angular app.

Comment: Then after building you will get index.html in dist folder, Just place your static index.html in production and rename the angular index.html file and write links in your static file to angular html file.