# How to serve static files in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I want to add robots.txt and sitemap.xml to the project, what is proper way to do that on Spartacus? Is it autogenerated or should we add it manually?

Comment: Did you try serving that by assets like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646504/how-to-serve-static-directory-from-ng-serve/44831102)?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those are autogenerated. You can generate them and add those manually to your shell app as you would with any angular application.